# Read timed out after 30,000 ms

Tags: eclipse

I am stackoverflow user.
I asked there a question [EGIT saying Read timed out after 30,000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740204/egit-saying-read-timed-out-after-30-000-ms)

One of the kind user there tried helping me but we couldnt resolve it.
so he suggested me to take my question to superuser as all solutions there couldnt solve my prob and he suspected its internet or proxy or firewall issue.

I am new here, and really dont know how to move stackoverflow question to superuser.
so had to make this new post...

kindly excuse me and please help me in resolving the issue.

details of question are:

Im trying to clone a remote repo over http in my local dest.
im using egit on eclipse luna.

but im always getting error read timed out after 30,000ms.

i know http is correct protocol for it, my username passsword is correct but still this problem occuring multiple times.

pls see screenshot in stackoverflow question for more clear idea. (im not allowed to post images here as I dont have enough reputation on Super User.

UPDDATE: 11-5-2014
When i saw eclipse error log at location *.metadata/log*
I saw following error message..... i think it says same.... but still adding here in case if it can help solving this problem....
error message is

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2014-11-05 19:09:13.827
!MESSAGE Read timed out after 30,000 ms
!STACK 0

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:156)
    at 

org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$6.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.readTimedOut(TimeoutInputStream.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readString(PacketLineIn.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readACK(PacketLineIn.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.negotiate(BasePackFetchConnection.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:356)
    ... 15 more
```

can anybody help me to resolve this prob?
thanks in advance !!

thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all details on the problem, just as you did on SO. We need them here in case your question is removed from SO at some point.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for suggestion ! I have added details from SO to here. Just couldnt post screenshot as I dont have enough reputation on Super User to post image. Hope this info will help in resolving issue.

Comment: Is it a really big repo? Can you clone it using the command line git tools? Are you running a local firewall that might prevent access or are you on a corporate network? 30 seconds is a lot of time.

Comment: Are you not able to clone any remote repo? Or just this one?

Answer (score 1):

I have a headache about GitHub.

1. there is a setting:window-->preference-->team-->git
   change "Remote connection timeout"'s value to 180.

this doesn't do work, but it may work sometime for my network is in a great wall.

2. find Git-->Configuration,there are "User Setting","System Setting" and "Repository Setting". Check "User Setting" and "System Setting" files are exist.
3. my problem is "User setting"(H:\myeclipse_git.gitconfig) exists but "System setting"(j:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig) do not. So I create `.gitconfig` in directory ect and copy U's(H:\myeclipse_git.gitconfig) content to it, save change and it works!

Now I've cloned the remote git project.

[image]